# Invoke a command on AWS EC2 instance via Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, linux, amazon-ec2, google-apps-script, aws-lambda

I currently use a great Node package called gsheets to convert Google Sheets to JSON. This is done via the Amazon CLI using a command like below:

```
gsheets --key=1iOqNjB-mI15ZLly_9lqn1hCa6MinqPc_71RoKVyCFZs
```

The problem being I have to go into Amazon EC2 CLI every time to get the latest feed to my app after changes to the spreadsheet.

How can I invoke a CLI command from within Google Sheets, perhaps via a webhook within a Google App Script or triggering a Lambda function?

Struggling to find a solution to this

Comment: Got a "Trigger & Send" add-on in Google Sheets that sends to a webhook.youtube.com/watch?v=9QNJXIizaic . Just need a Webhook to Lambda and then execute the EC2 script via Lambda.(If this is the best way to do this)

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? Seems interesting...